# Laser engraving - best wavelength?

Tags: laser

I have been looking at engraving machines. Ones using high power lasers vary from the 10.6u high power CO2 and NdYAG types to diode devices below 10W ranging from near IR to red to blue.

I primarily want to engrave metal (brass). What are optimum powers and wavelengths for the absorption of laser energy interacting with various metals?

Comment: This is not an engineering question even in its original form

Comment: Related meta discussion: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9251/2451

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, asking about the configuration for an engraving machine is absolutely an engineering question. If you were asking something about _why_ certain wavelengths would be more effective for certain metals, then it would more likely be a physics question and on topic here.

Comment: @DavidZ Well, I edited the question to make it about lasers, wavelengths and high power interactions with metals. The reason that I want to know should not have a bearing on the question from this site's POV

Comment: And as an added comment, I find this site almost useless from an experimental physics POV. I have argued before about questions that got classed as "engineering" and wasted a lot of time getting such questions rephrased. Then almost inevitably finding out that nobody knows the answer. I have complained about this before on meta

Comment: Finally, if this does not get re-opened I am no longer going to waste my time with this site. I am pissing about in work time writing this and apparently getting nowhere

Comment: While I agree with @DirkBruere that experimental questions can be given short shrift here, I don't see this as one of them. This question is when you call the various companies, talk to the service engineers about your particular application, and send them samples of your material for them to engrave and send back for inspection (this is almost always free). Or, go to a trade show and have them do it on the spot. The application space is so broad that, without knowing all the details of what you want to do nobody can give you a particularly useful answer.